# How do i get the relative path with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I recognize that this has been asked before but I have yet to find an answer that is working for me.  I'm basically following a solution for keeping an ASP session alive I found at [dotnetcurry by Malcom Sheridan](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=453).

I have the following JQuery defined on the masterpage of an asp.net site.  As the default page is on the same level, it has no problems making the serverside call every 7 seconds; however, when I navigate to another page, deeper in the file structure, the ajax post starts to fail.

```
var interval;
$(function () {
    setheartbeat();
});

function setheartbeat() {
    interval = setInterval("heartbeat()", 7000);
}

function heartbeat() {
    $.post("./SessionHeartbeat.ashx", null, function (data) {

    })
    .done(function () {
        alert('done');
    })
    .fail(function () {
        clearInterval(interval);
        alert('Failed to keep session alive.  Please close the browser and log back in.');           
    });
}
```

Besides the sample from above, I've already tried, with none of them working:

1. $.post("/SessionHeartbeat.ashx", null, function(data) {...}
2. $.post(window.location.pathname + "/SessionHeartbeat.ashx", null, function(data) {...}
3. $.post(vpath + "/SessionHeartbeat.ashx", null, function(data) {...} where vpath = "<%=ApplicationVirtualPath %>"; after I've included the System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment namespace

Anyone have any thoughts?

Thank you

Comment: The relative paths should always be used in such a way that its always one level down to the servername. In your case , if your application url is www.servername.com and the path to the handler is  www.servername.com/data/handlers//SessionHeartbeat.ashx , then you should just do : $.post("/data/handlers//SessionHeartbeat.ashx on every page.

Comment: I would avoid relative paths if I were you. They're tricky to keep correct in an ASP.NET environment. From your page, pass down the root of your site, and then use an absolute URL to refer to specific endpoints on the server.