# Why does a masterpage's UpdatePanel trigger event also trigger an UpdatePanel in a content page?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have the following updatepanel in the masterpage:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="pnlHeartBeat" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="HeartBeat" EventName="Tick" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Timer runat="server" id="HeartBeat" Interval="180000" OnTick="Heartbeat_OnTick"></asp:Timer>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This runs fine no matter where I am in the site... right up to the point I navigate to a content page with another updatepanel, after which whenever the masterpage's updatepanel is triggered, so will the content page's updatepanel.

Here's a content page updatepanel:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="ajaxColumnGroups" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="cboxAllorNone" EventName="CheckedChanged" />
    </Triggers>
    <contenttemplate>
        <dx:ASPxCheckBox ID="cboxAllorNone" runat="server" text="Select/Deselect All" OnCheckedChanged="cboxAllorNone_CheckChanged" autopostback="true"></dx:ASPxCheckBox> 
        <dx:ASPxPageControl runat="server" id="tabColumnGroups" ActiveTabIndex="0"></dx:ASPxPageControl>
    </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

How can I stop this behavior?
Thanks

Comment: You probably don't want to hear this, but you should abandon UpdatePanel completely. It will save you a lot of headaches. Most of the time what you're trying to accomplish would be better to do with client side code anyways.

Comment: eh, I don't mind hearing it.  In fact, I have already have a version of it with client-side code but ran into other problems.  Check it out if you've the time:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34516766/how-do-i-get-the-relative-path-with-jquery

Comment: what does the request body look like when the timer triggers the async postback?